# Read XML and get data in ASP.net Web application

Tags: asp.net, xml

I need to find coSpaces total="3" value from the below XML in ASP.net C#. Please help me with the xmlreader code. I have seen other tutorial where I can find element value but not this type.

Thanks,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<coSpaces total="3">
    <coSpace id="0">
        <name>A</name>
        <autoGenerated>false</autoGenerated>
    </coSpace>
    <coSpace id="2">
        <name>B</name>
        <autoGenerated>false</autoGenerated>
    </coSpace>
    <coSpace id="4">
        <name>C</name>
        <autoGenerated>false</autoGenerated>
    </coSpace>`
</coSpaces>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get `total` in this way:

```
private static string GetTotal()
{
    var document = new XmlDocument();
    using (var file = new FileStream("file.xml", FileMode.Open))
    {
        using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(file))
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.IsStartElement())
                {
                    var attr = reader["total"];

                    return attr;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking a minute to learn XPath, and the 2 methods that use it (SelectSingleNode, and SelectNodes) will really help in a lot of situations.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;

namespace testconsole
{
        class Program
        {
                public static string strFileName = "c:\\temp\\test.xml";
                static void Main(string[] args) {
                        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
                        xml.Load(strFileName);

                        XmlElement ndMatch = (XmlElement) xml.SelectSingleNode("//coSpaces[@total=3]");
                        if (ndMatch != null) {
                                foreach (XmlElement ndCoSpace in ndMatch.SelectNodes("coSpace")) {
                                        Console.Write(ndCoSpace.GetAttribute("id"));
                                }
                        } else {
                                Console.Write("Not found in " + strFileName);
                        }




                }
        }
}
```